# Electorate badge not awarded

Tags: support, badges, electorate-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Condition to get the *Electorate* badge is:

> Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

Have a look at [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356150/prasad-jadhav), I have voted on almost 700 questions and more than 50% of them are questions.

What else do I need to get the Electorate badge?

Comment: have you **Voted on 600 questions** ?

Comment: [All Badges Descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/173001)

Comment: thanks Lucifer. Now I get it the exact meaning of the Electrolate Badge Condition.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have voted on 374 questions. 716 is total votes. You need to vote minimum 600 **questions**. Not total votes.

Look at your votes cast:

[image]

#### Electorate

- Vote on 600 questions, and have at least **25% of the total number of votes** cast be votes on questions

[From votes](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down)

> #### When should I vote up?
>
> Whenever you encounter a question or answer that you feel is
> especially useful, vote it up!
>
> #### When should I vote down?
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy,
> no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps
> dangerously incorrect.

**So PLEASE don't cast votes for gold badge.**

Comment: In the condition of electrolate Badge, what does "25%" indicate?

Comment: 25% of total votes **+** minimum 600 on **questions**.

Comment: It means that at least 25% of the votes that you've cast have been on questions, @Prasad. You haven't fulfilled that requirement for the electorate badge, nor have you fulfilled the requirement to vote on 600 questions.

Comment: Thanks all. Sorry I misinterpreted it. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 6):

You have voted only on 374 questions and total votes are 715.

See how Electorate Badge works,

#### Electorate

- gold; awarded once; same family as Civic Duty (silver)
- Vote on 600 questions, and have at least 25% of the total number of votes cast be votes on questions

  - Comment votes do not count

This seems to be an especially confusing badge, so here are some examples to address cases commonly complained about on MSO. `Total` is just the total number of votes cast (`Questions` + `Answers`) and `Ratio` is the total number of votes cast that are on questions.

```
┌───────────┬─────────┬───────┬───────┬─────────────────────┐  
│ Questions │ Answers │ Total │ Ratio │ Electorate awarded? │  
├───────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────┤  
│       600 │    2400 │  3000 │   20% │   No; ratio too low │  
│       201 │     401 │   602 │  ~33% │ No; < 600 questions │  
│       599 │       0 │   599 │  100% │ No; < 600 questions │  
│       600 │       0 │   600 │  100% │                 Yes │  
│       500 │     500 │  1000 │   50% │ No; < 600 questions │  
│       650 │     650 │  1300 │   50% │                 Yes │  
└───────────┴─────────┴───────┴───────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Original [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/173001)

Comment: Confusing badge, but the table really helps hammer home how it works.

Comment: @jmort253, agree with you, i was confused too before seeing this table. This table shows very simple description, Thanks to the original creator.